# Render html partial with js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial

I want to render html partial with js respond_to

Here is my controller:

```html
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.ransack(first_name_or_last_name_cont: params[:query]).result(distinct: true)
    @teams = Team.ransack(name_cont: params[:query]).result(distinct: true)
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
      format.json {}
      @users = @users.limit(5)
      @teams = @teams.limit(5)
    end
    
  end
end
```

Here is my index.js.erb:

```js
$('<%= j render :partial => 'result_list' %>')
```

It works but it don't display html correctly in my search dropdown

I have something like this:

```html
$('
\n\nUsers\n<\/span>\n\n\n<\/i>\n<\/span>\nCharlotte Marie<\/span>\n<\/a>\n\n\n<\/i>\n<\/span>\nMatrice .io<\/span>\n<\/a>\n\n\n\"Maboukra\"\n<\/span>\nMichael Aboukrat<\/span>\n<\/a>\n\n\n<\/i>\n<\/span>\nConstance Albanel<\/span>\n<\/a>\n\n\n\"Malberte\"\n<\/span>\nMatthieu
```

Please let me know the right js code

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering the whole HTML partial directly into the $() tag, which is not correct. Keep in mind that what Rails does is to load the Javascript inside the `js.erb` file.

Instead, you should load it into another HTML element, something like:

```
<span id="container"></span>
```

and then, make the HTML inside it to be the partial you want to render, so in the `index.js.erb` you should write:

```
$('#container').html("<%= j render partial: 'result_list' %>");
```